# webbrowser submit from vb.net doesnt work

Tags: vb.net, browser

I tried to ask this question once before but I didnt supply enough info.  I have a form on a web site that I do not control so I can't change the web.  From my vb.net app I need to be able to click the submit button after I fill out the needed text.

The text fills in ok, but the submit just refreshes the screen.  I am wondering if I have to call Java or something?

The VBNet part looks this this:

```
Browser1.Document.Forms("Search").submit
```

I also tried this:

```
 Browser1.Document.GetElementById("Search").InvokeMember ("submit")
```

The web page html is this:

```
<form style="display: inline;" name="Search" method="post" 

onsubmit="clearDefault(this.freetext); this.action=addCategory(escape(this.freetext.value) + this.category_id.value + '.html'); return true;">

    <table class="innerTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr>
        <td><input style="width: 131px;" value=" enter name" name="freetext" size="9" onfocus="clearDefault(this);" type="text"></td>



        <td><input class="search" src="/images/search.gif" value="Search" title="Search" type="image"></td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `InvokeMember("click")` ?

```
Browser1.Document.GetElementById("Search").InvokeMember("click")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set .AllowNavigation property to "TRUE"

```
Browser1.AllowNavigation = True
```

And call submit method like this

```
Browser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

Or

```
Browser1.Document.Forms.GetElementsByName("Search").Item(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```